# GoogleTest with Templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c-preprocessor, googletest

Hope this question will not be too stupid. I'm quite new in using gtest and it's been quite a very long time that I don't make use of C++.
Let suppose w have this simplistic template `Point` class:

```
template <class T>
    struct Point
{
    union
    {
        T _data [2];
        struct { T x, y; };
    };
    constexpr Point(T x_, T y_) noexcept : x(x_), y(x_) {}
};
```

Then using gtest, I'm trying to check if `Point` is default constructible:

```
TEST_P(PointTest,Concept)
{
    ASSERT_TRUE(std::is_nothrow_constructible<Point<float>,float,float>::value);
}
```

Then I get this compilation error with Clang 6.0.1 with C++11 flags:

```
"error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation"
```

Any help will be welcome. I do know that special care must be taken when combining templates and googletest. But I didn't figure out a solution.
Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it's a problem with C++ preprocessor that recognize the commas between templates arguments

```
// ...................................................v.....v
ASSERT_TRUE(std::is_nothrow_constructible<Point<float>,float,float>::value);
```

as macros arguments separators.

I suggest to calculate the value outside the macro call

```
TEST_P(PointTest,Concept)
{
   constexpr auto val 
      = std::is_nothrow_constructible<Point<float>, float, float>::value;

   ASSERT_TRUE( val );
}
```

or to pass through a `using` for the type

```
TEST_P(PointTest ,Concept)
{
   using inc = std::is_nothrow_constructible<Point<float>, float, float>;

   ASSERT_TRUE( inc::value );
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, @max66! Your suggestion solves my problem.